# How can I upload files using extended data for a subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am uploading multiple files in a web page on a form submit.  The form submit is handled through breezejs for its form data but the files need to be uploaded to a specific sub-directory in the uploads directory based on a unique identifier returned from the submit.

I can't figure out how to get the sub-directory information from the Post request in time to apply it to the path variable when initializing the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`.

My `ApiController` for the upload:

```
public class UploadingController : ApiController
{
    private const string FolderName = "uploads";

    [HttpPost]
    public Task<IEnumerable<FileDescription>> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));

        var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + FolderName));

        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

            var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
            {
                var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                var rootUrl = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, String.Empty);

                return new FileDescription(info.Name, string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", rootUrl, FolderName, info.Name), info.Length / 1024);
            });
            return fileInfo;
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

My `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` implementation:

```
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path)
    {}

    public override string GetLocalFileName(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        var name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName) ? headers.ContentDisposition.FileName : "NoName";
        return name.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

My js service calls the WebAPI using this function:

```
var uploadFiles = function (files, subDirectory) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('subDirectory', subDirectory);
    for (var i = 0; i < files().length; i++)
        data.append('items[]', files()[i]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: config.contextPath + 'api/Uploading',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (res) {
            $.each(res, function (j, item) {
                logger.info('File uploaded: ' + item.name + ' to path: ' + item.path);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

The `data.append('subDirectory', subDirectory)` should give me access to this as part of the `NameValueCollection` in `FormData`.  I can't access this collection before instantiating the `StreamProvider` though, which requires a directory path to instantiate.

How do I pass this sub-directory to the `StreamProvider` for creating these sub-directories?